# How to divide all entries in two lists into one

Tags: python-3.x

I want to take two lists such as:

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [2, 4, 8, 1]
```

And receive this result. How would I go about doing this?

`result = [1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/1, 2/2, 2/4, 2/8, 2/1]`

The list could contain more entries so it needs to be able to adapt to the number of entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a list comprehension:

```
result = [n/d for n in list1 for d in list2]
```

This relies on the fact that `list2` does not contain any 0 (you can't divide by 0).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product` and `operator.truediv` and instead of `map` you can use `itertools.starmap`

```
from itertools import starmap, product
from operator import truediv

list(starmap(truediv, product(list1, list2)))
```

Results:

```
[0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 2.0]
```

This is faster than a nested loop as product replaces the nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np
list2=1/np.array(list2)
x=np.outer(list1, list2).reshape(1,-1)[0]
```

Output:

```py
[0.5   0.25  0.125 1.    1.    0.5   0.25  2.   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want fractions then you can try:

```
from fractions import Fraction
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [2, 4, 8, 1]
[Fraction(n,d) for n in list1 for d in list2]

[Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(1, 8), Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(2, 1)]
```

However you can see that this won't preserve fractions which can be simplified, e.g. 2/8 --> 1/4